# What does VB.Net For Each Loop look at to Infer the Type

Tags: vb.net, generics, foreach, type-inference

In the following code,

```
For Each item in MyCollection
...
Next
```

What does the compiler use to determine the type of `item`?

For example let say I have this class, which is inheriting a non generic collection,

```
Public Class BaseDataObjectGenericCollection(Of T)
    Inherits BaseDataObjectCollection
End Class
```

A for each loop still infers the Item type as `Object`. How would I have to modify the above class to make the type inference work?

Edit: Per Beatles1692's answer, Implementing IEnumerator(Of T) kinda works. The base class already has a `GetEnumerator` function, inherited from `CollectionBase`, so I my implementation looked like this,

```
    Public Function GetEnumerator1() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of T) Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of T).GetEnumerator
        Return MyBase.Cast(Of T)().GetEnumerator
    End Function
```

However, the for loop still infers the type as object. But, if I change the interface implementation to this,

```
    Public Shadows Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of T) Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of T).GetEnumerator
        Return MyBase.Cast(Of T)().GetEnumerator
    End Function
```

That works, the for loop gets the type inference correct. So I guess the question is now, does `For Each` just look for a function called `GetEnumerator` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's only one place to go for a question like this. The spec!

Section 10.9.3 discusses For Each statements. According to it:

> [if] local variable type inference is being used, then the identifier defines a new local variable whose scope is the entire For loop and whose type is the element type of the collection (Object if the enumerator expression is typed as Object).

"collection" here seems vague, but it's precisely defined on the next page. Essentially, the type must have a GetEnumerator() call, and this enumerator must (a) have a `MoveNext()` method that returns a boolean type, and (b) have a  `Current` property. The type of the Current property is the type that will be inferred by the compiler. Note it actually has nothing to do with IEnumerator or IEnumerable...you just have to fit the prescribed pattern. Consider this code:

```
Option Infer On

Public Module M
    Sub Main()
        For Each x In New SomeClass()

        Next
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class SomeClass
    Public Function GetEnumerator() As MyEnumerator
        Return New MyEnumerator()
    End Function
End Class


Public Class MyEnumerator
    Public ReadOnly Property Current As Integer
        Get
            Return 42
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function MoveNext() As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

The type of "x" in the Sub Main() is Integer, since the Current property returns Integer.

Comment: It all makes sense now. I'll have to remember to check the spec next time. I always rely on Google to figure out what I want from a jumble of words.

Answer (score 1):

Either you should write :

```
For Each Item As SpecificType In MyCollection
....
Next
```

Then it will cast Item to SpecificType in each loop or your collection should have implemented IEnumerable(Of T)

Comment: Yes, but not what I was asking. I want to know how the compiler infers the type, when its not supplied.

Comment: Ok, I'll give you that. See my edited answer, when I tried it out I got some strange results. Still curious if anyone knows what exactly the compiler is doing.

Comment: What do you mean by strange results ?

Comment: take a look at this article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4074/Using-IEnumerator-and-IEnumerable-in-the-NET-Frame

Comment: I guess strange that I assumed that it would follow the interface definition, but it didn't. I also tried taking out the interface definition and just leaving the `GetEnumerator` function by itself and it still worked. So it appears to not care about the interface at all, only that there is a function specifically named `GetEnumerator`. I just find that odd.

Comment: @Kratz that behavior is to avoid boxing penalties in non-generic collections of value types in pre .NET 2.0 days.