# Find the length of a word in an array - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a richtextbox and I converted the words to an array, then I have code that will take the length and the output it... only problem is I don't know how to loop through all the different values of the array to check the length of each individual part of the array.

(I have this set on TextChanged)

```
        Dim len1, len2, len3, len4, len5, len6, len7, len8, len9, len10, len11, len12, len13, len14, len15 As Integer
    Dim input As String
    Dim words As String()
    Dim length As Integer

    input = RichTextBox1.Text


    words = input.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    For Each w In words

        length = Len(w)

        Select Case length


            Case 1
                len1 = len1 + 1
            Case 2
                len2 = len2 + 1
            Case 3
                len3 = len3 + 1
            Case 4
                len4 = len4 + 1
            Case 5
                len5 = len5 + 1
            Case 6
                len6 = len6 + 1
            Case 7
                len7 = len7 + 1
            Case 8
                len8 = len8 + 1
            Case 9
                len9 = len9 + 1
            Case 10
                len10 = len10 + 1
            Case 11
                len11 = len11 + 1
            Case 12
                len12 = len12 + 1
            Case 13
                len13 = len13 + 1
            Case 14
                len14 = len14 + 1
            Case 15
                len15 = len15 + 1

        End Select

    Next








    letcount.onelet.Text = Val(len1)
    letcount.twolet.Text = Val(len2)
    letcount.threelet.Text = Val(len3)
    letcount.fourlet.Text = Val(len4)
    letcount.fivelet.Text = Val(len5)
    letcount.sixlet.Text = Val(len6)
    letcount.sevenlet.Text = Val(len7)
    letcount.eightlet.Text = Val(len8)
    letcount.ninelet.Text = Val(len9)
    letcount.tenlet.Text = Val(len10)
    letcount.elevenlet.Text = Val(len11)
    letcount.twelevelet.Text = Val(len12)
    letcount.thirteenlet.Text = Val(len13)
    letcount.fourteenlet.Text = Val(len14)
    letcount.fifteenlet.Text = Val(len15)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused... What are you trying to accomplish here - Seems like there should be a much more efficient way....

Comment: What did you try? I know you posted some code but I see no attempt to loop through the words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David,

Some clarification for you:

w is a string. The compiler determines the type at design time. See this S.O. thread
[What does VB.Net For Each Loop look at to Infer the Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369803/what-does-vb-net-for-each-loop-look-at-to-infer-the-type)

```
Dim words() As String = {"0", "1", "2"}
For Each w In words
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(w)
Next
```

The type is inferred by the compiler by looking at the elements in the IEnumerable collection (array, list, etc.) The intellisense even knows it's a string at design time, even when w looks like it is defined as a generic. Try it yourself...

BUT. You can of course add the type explicitly

```
Dim words() As String = {"0", "1", "2"}
For Each w As String In words
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(w)
Next
```

The string array example doesn't really demonstrate the convenience of the shorthand. See below

```
Dim dictionaryOfDictionaries As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
For Each d As KeyValuePair(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)) In dictionaryOfDictionaries
    ' do something with each dictionary d
Next
' is identical to
For Each d In dictionaryOfDictionaries
    ' do something with each dictionary d
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was able to get it to work. I edited the orginal code with my final code.

Answer (score 1):

bendataclear showed you how to use a For Next loop.  If you can use LINQ, you can use the following code:

```
Sub Main
    Dim words As String() = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" }

    Dim lengthsOnly = words.Select(Function(w) w.Length).ToArray()

    Dim wordsAndLengths = words.Select(Function(w) New With { .Word = w, .Length = w.Length }).ToArray()

End Sub
```

The first Select gets only the word lengths, the second returns an array with each word and it's length.

Comment: I'm a month and a half new to VB, so I don't know what LINQ is or how to incorporate it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use another array?

```
Dim arr(14) as integer

Dim input As String
Dim words As String()
Dim length As Integer

input = RichTextBox1.Text

words = Split(input, " ")

For Each w in words

    Dim l as Integer = Math.Min(Len(w) - 1,14)
    arr(l) = arr(l) + 1

Next
```

**Edit**

In answer to questions in the comment:

`w` is a variable, and it is declared in the shortcut code `For Each w in words`

The shortcut declares a variable `w` then populates it with each member of the array `words` and runs the code between the `For` and `next`.

A longer way to do this without the shortcut would be something like:

```
Dim i as Integer

For i = 0 to words.GetUpperBound(0) -1

    Dim w as string

    w = words(i)

    i = i + 1

    'Rest of code

Next i
```

The next part `Dim l as Integer = Math.Min(Len(w) - 1,14)` sets `l` to the length of the word up to 14, as if we have a word longer than 15 letters it won't fit in the array.

Another way to do it would be:

```
Dim l as Integer 

l = Len(w) - 1

If l > 14 then
    l = 14
End If

arr(l) = arr(l) + 1
```

Comment: ok, this makes sense to me, just 2 questions: 1. is "w" a variable that you didn't declare? or what is it? also what exactly is the Dim l as Integer = Math.Min(Len(w) - 1,14)
    arr(l) = arr(l) + 1" part doing ? Do I need to do arr(2), arr(3) etc. for the other lengths? Thanks.

Comment: I'm leaning more towards the second method you provided, VB is saying UBound is not part of system.array "words" .. In that code ... what is w = words(i) doing?

Comment: Sorry `Ubound` is from VB6, correct method for .net would be `GetUpperBound(0)`, added to the example above.

Comment: Ok i added that to the code (I'm pretty sure i'm doing something wrong though)..(I edited the code i origianally posted with the changes)

Comment: You're not setting the `length` variable after each iteration, you need to add a `length = Len(w)`.

Comment: Thanks for the length = len(w) part :) It helped me complete the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore double spaces and enters because they are considered empty:

```
    'HOW CAN I EXCLUDE DOUBLE SPACES 
    'AND INCLUDE IF SOMEBODY PRESSES ENTER?
    words = input.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: I just noticed that when I press enter it considers it another letter of the word until I enter a space ... also how could i ignore "." "/" "," "()" etc... ... input = input.remove("/") ?

Comment: Ok i was able to remove "." but how would I do it for "Enter" ?

Comment: David, I am not at work and don't have VS installed where I am. I can look at it tomorrow. For now, look into

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx